# Reference error: el is not defined. how to fix this error

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that adds a row to a table (UI) and the data array

```
const populateData = (device) => {
    document.getElementById("content").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        <tr class='data' id=${device.tt}>
        <th scope="row">${device.tt}</th>
        <td>${device.ma}</td>
        <td>${device.ten}</td>
        <td>${device.DVT}</td>
        <td>${device.trongLuong}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick='deleteData(this)'>Xóa</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sửa</button>
        </td>
    </tr>)
}

const init = () => devices.forEach(device => {
    populateData(device);
});

const addData = () => {
    const maSo = document.getElementById("ma-sp").value;
    const ten = document.getElementById("ten-sp").value;
    const dvt = document.getElementById("dvt").value;
    const trongLuong = document.getElementById("trong-luong").value;
    if (maSo === '' || ten === '' || dvt === '' || trongLuong === '') {
        return;
    }
    const newData = {
        tt: devices.length + 1,
        ma: maSo,
        ten,
        DVT: dvt,
        trongLuong
    }
    devices.push(newData);
    return newData;
};

const addDataUI = () => {
   // add data to table
    const device = addData();
    populateData(device);
    //close modal 
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
};
```

However when I try to implement the deleteData 
method the filter function does not work, returning an error: "ReferenceError: el is not defined"

```
const deleteData = (x) => {
    const row = x.parentNode.closest('tr');
    //delete device (error is here)
    const row = x.parentNode.closest('tr');
    devices = devices.filter(el => el !== row.getAtrribute('id'));
    console.log(devices);
document.getElementById("devices").deleteRow(x.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex);   }
```

The console.log(devices) code returns the whole array without filtering as a result.

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: can you log `devices`

Comment: You look like you're using your filter incorrectly: You need to declare what your filter is, and then hand that into .filter() have a read of: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter

Comment: @Sweet - was there a mention of RamdaJS?

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly I think the OP is right. This is another way of doing this. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Once the devices array is no longer empty :-) - The problem with the filter is that `devices` appears to be an Array of `newData` objects. So `el` would equal a single `newData` - an Object is not equal to -1. So - devices will end up being -- empty :-)

Comment: Provide all info in your console tab of develop tool, I think you can find exactly the line what throws the error.

Comment: There's no error in the console. I found the error through the debugging tool...

Comment: If you run `devices = [1, 2, 3];` `const deleteData = (x) => { devices = devices.filter(el => el !== 1); }` `deleteData();` `console.log(devices);` everything works and the output is `[2, 3]`

Comment: This does not appear to be valid Javascript. Did you forget to add the relvant tags like [tag:jsx] [tag:reactjs]?